# Laravel blade.php Files don't load in WAMP

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, wamp, laravel-blade

I'm trying to load a .blade.php view with Laravel in WAMP. I have to view files for testing, test.php and test2.blade.php. When I load the non-blade view with

```
return View::make('test');
```

it works fine, but when I try to load the other view that uses blade like so

```
return View::make('test2');
```

I get an error

```
 ErrorException
file_put_contents(D:\wamp\www\...\app\storage/views/407b5542021a967efb057132e71652cc):failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

One thing I notice is that views in Laravel are in '\app\view', but when loading the .blade.php view it's trying to load it from '\app\storage/views'. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that Laravel is trying to write data to your **storage/view** file, but it doesn't have permissions (write access). Storage/view is a folder for caching view files.It is default Laravel behaviour, so change permissions on whole storage folder, becuse there is more files inside, that Laravel will try to use for other purposes. For example, **services.json** is used when you add new service provider, and if it is locked, Laravel will complain.

Comment: okay that makes sense, but through the windows security options I've given the folder 'full control' access to any user on the system and it's still complaining. at times like this I wish i was working in LAMP instead of WAMP so i could just use chmod. any advice?

Comment: okay so the 'storage' folder had its permissions correct, but since the 'storage/views' folder didn't exist (I'm assuing it's created and destroyed on the fly by Laravel?) windows wasn't giving that folder the same permissions. I just manually created a 'storage/views' folder, and it works just fine. seems like a dumb workaround, but it works